# Displaying text from database. Dissapears when page is refreshed

Tags: php

I'm currently building a social network from home and have a very nice looking newsfeed. Now I'm able to post my status to the database and it pops up underneath, just like Facebook's newsfeed. However, when I refresh the page the status I inputted disappears and wondering if someone could tell me where I may have gone wrong as Dreamweaver isn't showing any errors within my code.

I have checked my database and the status is still in there, just the box with the inputted text disappears completely from view.

Here is my status code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?PHP 
//Include connection to database
include('connect_to_mysql.php');

//Get posted values from form
$status=$_POST['status'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

//Strip slashes
$status = stripslashes($status);
$date = stripslashes($date);

//Strip tags 
$status = strip_tags($status);
$date = strip_tags($date);

//Inset into database
$insert_status=mysql_query("INSERT INTO status (status, date) VALUES('$status','$date')") or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($insert_status)){
$status=$row['status'];
$date=$row['date'];
}


//Line break after every 80
$status = wordwrap($status, 80, "\n", true);

//Line breaks
$status=nl2br($status);

//Display status from data base
echo '<div class="load_status">
<div class="status_img"><img src="blankSilhouette.png" /></div>
<div class="status_text"><a href="#" class="blue">Test Name</a><p class="text">'.$status.'</p>
<div class="date">'.$date.' &middot; <a href="#" class="light_blue">Like</a> &middot; <a href="#" class="light_blue">Comment</a></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

But $status is only set if you posted it from a previous page, if you didnt post one, on refresh it never goes to read it from the database. You could start there.

Comment: See just how facebook status works, is exactly how mine does. In the text input field I added text 'test', it sent that 'test' to my database and returned it underneath the input field in my browser.

Comment: Thats fine, however, you still need at some point to read in previous entries. Unless you're using another page to do that somewhere else. Otherwise, the page will be basically blanket as $status will be empty. As this page, inserts 2 values, assuming they are there, I would expect its either erroring, or, returning nothing as the only line you've read in is the one you posted, not any previously sent entries.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this coding, so I'm a tad confused. I have my wall.php that calls upon the above code!

Comment: Here is the Newsfeed as example. Maybe you could tell me what I'm missing if possible. I'm greatly appreciative of your time to help and I do not wish to take too much of it up if possible. http://www.fightstar.org/test/wall.php

Comment: OK, but we cant see that can we?  All you've shown us, is some code that assumes theres 2 variables, and tries to write them to a database, if that fails, because the variables dont exist, or whatever, it will read nothing.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `status` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` text NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

Comment: My wall.php is so huge I'd have to split it up to show you what is on that page..Would you like me to do so?

Comment: I've missed this code out just beneath VALUES. $get_status=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status BY id DESC") 
or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_status)){ but now I'm getting this error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY id DESC' at line 1

Comment: @David: you probably meant `ORDER BY`. But even fixing that, the main issues (messing up the POST with the generation of the page) remain, take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing all your replies to BugFinder's answer, and that you mention that you are new to this coding, maybe we should go back to the most basic concepts:

Let's look at how the client and server interact with each other:

The client (typically a browser) starts the communication by sending a *request* to the server. The server then processes the request, sends a *response*, and then it just forgets about it. It's because of this that HTTP is said to be a "stateless" protocol: there is no "state" saved between requests; on each request everything starts from zero.

Now, let's look at how the server processes requests: when a "static" resource (such a HTML document, an image, etc) is requested, the server just sends a copy of the file. However, when the resource is dynamic (like a PHP script), the server *executes* it, and sends the output of the execution back to the client (instead of sending the script itself).

Here comes one of the key parts: when you refresh a page from the browser, your browser simply repeats the original request. In this case, because it is a PHP script (a dynamic resource), the script is executed again (everything starts from zero, remember).

And the other key aspect: you are using AJAX (through jquery it seems). An AJAX request is just a request made on the background, normally asynchronously (this means that the javascript on the page can be doing other stuff while waiting for a response), and then does something with the response.

With those bases, let's look deeper at what's going on with your application:

You go to the "initial" page, either by typing the address on your browser or following a link. This causes your browser to send a "GET" request to the server, the server sends the "initial" page as a response, and the browser renders it (after that, the server forgets everything about that request).

Then you type something in the box and click the "Share" button. The javascript code (which is run by the browser, unlike the PHP which runs on the server) reacts to the click by sending a background "POST" request (the AJAX request) to the server. To process the request, the server executes the PHP script (which inserts the data on the database) and sends the result back to the browser. Because it was a "background" request, the browser hands that response to the javascript that started the request. The javascript then doesn't even look at what the response says: it just updates the "status" line with the data it already had (the same data it sent to the server).

And then you refresh the page. Refreshing a page just means asking the browser to repeat the original request (in this case, the "GET" request). And you get the same result as when you originally loaded it, despite it is not what you want.

---

Now, let's go to the juicy part: comparing what your code is doing vs. what you want it to do, and seeing why those don't match.

You seem to be mixing together the logics to serve the main page and the logics to handle the "background" requests sent by your javascript. You probably hoped that the server would simply know what you meant, but it just doesn't. When you refresh the page, the server doesn't "remember" that you had inserted stuff on the database (the server itself forgets about a request as soon as it sends the response).

Also, looking at your code it seems that you are trying to insert the data even when there is no data to insert; it's possible that you will be bloating your DB with loads of blank rows.

So this is what you should try to do:

1. On your PHP script, you need to figure out whether it has been invoked directly by the browser to get into the main page, or it was the javascript sending some data. Checking whether the $_POST fields are defined/non-blank may help with this. Another way to handle the distinction (which is very advisable for beginners) is to have separate scripts for each task: doing lots of different things on a single script makes it more complex, and you should really aim for simplicity until you get more familiar with the scripting languages you use and the HTTP protocol that stands in between.
2. When you are receiving the POST data, you know that it's the JS who is calling you, so after inserting the data all you should send as response is some message to let the JS know that everything went fine. It would also be a good idea to check that your "INSERT" command to the DB was indeed successful: if it wasn't, this is your best chance to report back the issue to the JS, so the JS can show a relevant error message.
3. When you are not receiving the POST data, your goal is to generate the "initial" page, but including whatever status that might be on the database. Keep in mind that the server doesn't remember at all that you did a POST previously. The data (if you already sent it) is on the database, but the server doesn't know, nor even cares, how did that data get there. So you can't look on $_POST for the data, because nothing is being posted on the current request. Where you want to look for the data is on the database itself, and you'll achieve this by issuing a `SELECT` command in a similar fashion on how you issued the `INSERT`. The `SELECT`, if properly done, will yield the data you need, and then you can use it to populate the contents of the page it will send back as the response for this request.

---

Facebook is a vast and rather complex software system. Keep in mind that it was done by *experienced* programmers, and it took quite a while. Cloning its functionality will definitely be tough. And even tougher if you are just starting.

However, if you really have the wits to go on with this, then we will be here to help. There are several sources you should keep handy: the PHP documentation, a good JavaScript reference, some jQuery reference, and the MySQL manual are the bare minimums.

Also, don't try to get everything done at once. Not even the most skilled gurus can deal with so much together. Start with something very basic, and then add a feature/function at a time. To build each feature, first do it on a separate, simple page or script, aimed to test just that feature. Once it is done and tested, integrate it into the whole project, and test that everything fits together as it should. Then, and only then, you could/should start with the next feature. Even the quickest sprinters need to run one step at a time ;)

Another bonus of this "divide and conquer" methodology is that if you are dealing with a single task at a time, it will be a lot easier to find tutorials, references, and help in general about that task. On each step, search the web (some people would say "Google is your friend", but feel free to use the search engine of your choice), search the relevant documentation, try to find a solution via "trial & error", and, when everything else fails, ask for help on forums or this place. Then you will be able to get more concise answers because you'll be asking more concise questions.

And last, but not least: do not fall in the trap of blind-pasting code. Even if you blindly trust the source and are confident that it will work, you should review any third-party code you add to your project and understand *how* it works, so you can adjust it to your needs/situation when you need to.

You are undertaking a very challenging project, and it's going to be a long, hard path until you reach your goal. The good thing is that you will have many opportunities to learn new things on each step: don't waste them, because they are what you'll be getting back from all the pain ;)

Hope this helps